# One-way binding a checkbox with [ngModel] does not work in Angular 6

Tags: angular, checkbox, redux, ngrx

We are developing an app with Angular 6 and NgRX (Redux-Pattern). I have a checkbox in my template **discovery.component.html**:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="wrongSpelling"
    [ngModel]="state.wrongSpelling" (click)="toggleWrongSpelling($event)" />
  Wrong Spelling
</label>
```

According to Redux-pattern, the dataflow should look like this:

1. User clicks on the checkbox. The checkbox is *not* toggled but an update action is dispatched. Also the `state` is *not updated* (**One-way binding**)
2. `render()`  is called with the new state and with the updated entity. The updated entity is assigned to the component.
3. The checkbox's state should update depending on the updated entity.

The relevant code of **discovery.component.ts** is given below:

```
public state;

render(state) {
  if (state.discovery) {
    this.state = state.discovery;
  }
}    

toggleWrongSpelling(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.discoveryAction.update({
    wrongSpelling: !this.state.wrongSpelling // it's safe that state exists here
  });
}
```

However, **the checkbox does not get checked on click**.

Things I'v tried (without success):

- Debugging `render()`: `this.state.wrongSpelling` is indeed toggled every time I click on the checkbox
- create a member in my DiscoveryComponent `wrongSpelling` which is toggled in `toggleWrongSpelling()` and read in the template (instead of the state) (I thought about changeDetection strategies that might be the problem here)
- used `[value]`, `[checked]` and (for testing) `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` in the template
- replaced `Wrong Spelling` with `{{ state.wrongSpelling }}` to see if there is a timing problem
- used the safe-navigation-operator: `[ngModel]="state?.wrongSpelling"`

so the problem seems to be in the template. **What could be wrong here?**

Comment: 1. did you include the `FormsModule` in your module? 2. `ngModel` is only available as part of an `NgForm`. Is the input part of a form? 3. `[value]` should work, but as a binding to a vanilla HTML element (not boolean - the name of the checkbox). Otherwise, `[checked]` should work as a boolean.

Comment: 1. Yes I did. 2. `ngModel` does indeed work without an `NgForm` (as it is shown in many Angular tutorials at the beginning of chapter "Two-Way data binding") 3. I built a workaround with `[(ngModel)]` now, which seems to work - but I still don't get why `[ngModel]` didn't

Comment: Just to be clear: `ngModel`, when used within a `<forn>` element on a control, will turn the `form` into an `ngForm`. I'm not sure if this only happens when two-way binding, but maybe try setting the `ngForm` explicitly to see if the one-way binding will then work.

Answer (score 2):

How about to use 'noop' option? Please try to add the following code in your component.

```
import { MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION, useValue: 'noop' }
  ],
})
```

'noop' option prevent to change the value of checkbox.

```
noop
Do not change the checked value or indeterminate value. 
Developers have the power to implement customized click actions.
```

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Comment: I was stuck for quite a bit because I'm using material ui with ngrx and I want to persist state but the async pipe doesn't work with mat checkbox because even if the observable is of type boolean the async pipe makes it boolean or null so I had to find a way around this and was getting constant state UI incongruities. Then I realized that material UI has it's own click handler and I need to stop that from happening. Thanks for your idea of noop. Now I can dispatch and action that returns a new state and the checkbox will update if I use formControlName="someName" instead of the [checked] input